# How to check if the pull request changes have fixed a bug on SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The Sonar Qube has reported some bugs in Overall Code on the long-live branches (main, release...). So, I fixed those issues then I created a Pull Request to a long-live branch. The Sonar Qube has analyzed my new PR and is not showing any report regarding the bug issues, neither on the old code nor on my new fixes. The report shows **0 Bugs new Bugs**. How to know if my changes have fixed the bugs?

I know that the PR analysis shows only stuff regarding the new code. But I'd like to know if my changes have been effective.